# How to destructure an object's property and property's properties. ES6 Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an object

```
const complicatedObject = {
  propertyA: {
    property1: 1,
    property2: 2
  },
  propertyB: {
    property1: 1,
    property2: 2
  }
}
```

If I want to grab `propertyA` I do

```
const { propertyA } = complicatedObject 

console.log(propertyA) // { property1: 1, property2: 2}
```

If I want to grab `propertyA's` `property1` value I do

```
const { propertyA: { property1 } } = complicatedObject

console.log(property1) // 1
```

I can grab `propertyA` and `propertyA's` `property1` this way.

```
const { 
  propertyA, 
  propertyA: { 
    property1 
  } 
} = complicatedObject

console.log(propertyA) // { property1: 1, property2: 2}
console.log(property1) // 1
```

Is there a simpler way to get both `propertyA` and `property1`?

I read the following but I felt like nothing jumped out to me as being the answer.

- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/
- http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#sec_more-obj-destructuring

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're looking for by "simpler"? Easier to read and write? Fewer characters of code?

Comment: Yes: `const { propertyA } = complicatedObject; const { property1 } = propertyA;` Two statements. Much simpler.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I feel like I shouldn't need to write the same thing twice; i.e. `propertyA` in the last snippet. I also feel like I shouldn't have to do this on two seperate lines.

Answer (score 3):

Just use two separate destructuring statements like so:

```
const { propertyA } = complicatedObject; 
const { property1 } = propertyA;
```

Demonstration:

```js
const complicatedObject = {
  propertyA: {
    property1: 1,
    property2: 2
  },
  propertyB: {
    property1: 1,
    property2: 2
  }
}
const { propertyA } = complicatedObject;
const { property1 } = propertyA;

console.log(propertyA);
console.log(property1);
```

However, if you want to use the most concise code possible, and just wanted `property1`'s value (`1`), you could use this method instead:

```
const { propertyA: { property1 } } = complicatedObject;
```

Demonstration:

```js
const complicatedObject = {
    propertyA: {
        property1: 1,
        property2: 2
    },
    propertyB: {
        property1: 1,
        property2: 2
    }
}
const { propertyA: { property1 } } = complicatedObject;
console.log(property1);
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I know this works but feel like we unneccesarily end up with an additional line of code as well as having to type `propertyA` twice.

Comment: plus 1 for readability, squeezing things into one statement isn't always "simpler".

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran Remember that the goal of writing good programs isn’t to write the least amount of code as possible — it’s to write concise code that people can easily understand and the machine can process quickly. Adding an extra line of code to assign a variable will not affect your program’s performance, and will only benefit people reading your code

Comment: @NickZuber I was just wondering if there was a technique I wasn't aware of. I feel like something like this could increase readability. Yes, although less code doesn't necessarily equate to readability; we can't deny that it often times can. Isn't this why destructuring was implemented in the first place? For example `const { propertyA } = complicatedObject` being easier to understand than `const propertyA = complicatedObject.propertyA`

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way:

```
const { 
  propertyA, 
  propertyA: { 
    property1 
  } 
} = complicatedObject
```

If you want to access both propertyA and property1 without using multiple declaration.

```
console.log(propertyA) // { property1: 1, property2: 2}
console.log(property1) // 1
```

---

But if I were you, I would do just like:

```
const { propertyA } = complicatedObject
console.log(propertyA)
console.log(propertyA.property1)
```

---

Or, using multiple declaration:

```
const { propertyA } = complicatedObject,
      { property1 } = propertyA
console.log(propertyA, property1)
```

---

Actually, the purpose of your post is to question to use like:

```
const { propertyA: { property1 } } = complicatedObject
console.log(propertyA, property1)
```

And I would say, this is not possible. Because, constructuring object with colon just behaves an alias to the property. For eg.

```
const { propertyA: A } = complicatedObject
console.log(A) // works as if it is propertyA
console.log(propertyA) // won't work because propertyA is transformed to A
```

In similar,

```
const { propertyA: { property1 } } = complicatedObject
```

`propertyA` is transformed to `{ property1 }` and can be accessed `property1`.

Also an alias to `property1`,

```
const { propertyA: { property1: prop1 } } = complicatedObject
console.log(prop1)
```