# How do I destructure this deep nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I have this function below:

```
const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
    if(!data) return;

    // add your code here

    clearNotice();
  };
```

the data parameter is an API from https://randomuser.me/api/

**The assignment has the instructions below:**

Locate the displayUserPhotoAndName function and do the follwing within it:

- After the first if(!data) return; statement that terminates the
  function if the expected data parameter is not provided, create a
  statement that de-structures the data parameter and obtains the
  results property from it;
- Create a second statement in the next line that de-structures the
  results variable you just created, and obtain the first item from it
  (it is an Array! See https://randomuser.me/api/). Your de-structured
  array item should be declared as profile. This represents the profile
  data for the user gotten from the API call that you want to display
  in your app.

**Step 3**
Still within the displayUserPhotoAndName function :

- Set the HEADING element in your app to display the title, last name,
  and first name (in that order, separated by a single space) of the
  user profile returned by the API.
- Set the IMG in your app to display the large photo of the user
  profile returned by the API.

**what I have done:**

```
const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
    if(!data) return;

    // add your code here
    const {results} = data.results;
    const [profile] = results;
    const {title, First, Last} = results;
    const [,,,,,,,,,picture] = results;
    const largeImage = picture.large;
    userImage.src = largeImage;
    headerUserInfo.innerText = title + ' ' +  First + ' ' + Last;
    clearNotice();
    displayExtraUserInfo(profile);
  };
```

The error I get:

> You have not de-structured the 'results' property from the 'data'
>   parameter passed to 'displayUserPhotoAndName' function

I'm in dire need of assistance. Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to provide you the full answer but giving you the hints:

```
const { results } = data
const { profile } = results
console.log(profile)
```

Can be written as:

```
const { results: { profile } } = data
console.log(profile)
```

Here are my some posts from which you may go further:

[destructure an objects properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893095/how-to-destructure-an-objects-property-and-propertys-properties-es6-javascrip/53893178#53893178)

[how is this type annotation working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351864/how-is-this-type-annotation-working-in-react-code-without-typescript/52352059#52352059)

[why source target when destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611156/why-sourcetarget-when-destructing-in-javascript/54611370#54611370)